# How to get the frame_width of an image with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I try to get the frame_width of an image with the following code:

```
    """Predict the gender of the faces showing in the image"""
    # Read Input Image
    img = cv2.imread(imag)
    # resize the image, uncomment if you want to resize the image
    img = cv2.resize(img, (frame_width, frame_height))
    # Take a copy of the initial image and resize it
    frame = img.copy()
    print(frame.shape[1])
    if frame.shape[1] > frame_width:
        frame = image_resize(frame, width=frame_width)
    # predict the faces
    faces = get_faces(frame)
```

Following my main method were I call the method with an image:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    predict_gender("/Users/$$$/Downloads/test.jpg")
```

I already tried to import tkinter because I thought I need tkinter for the frame but it was also not working. Here is my current error:

```
<ipython-input-10-2d047afa91e4> in predict_gender(imag)
      4     img = cv2.imread(imag)
      5     # resize the image, uncomment if you want to resize the image
----> 6     img = cv2.resize(img, (frame_width, frame_height))
      7     # Take a copy of the initial image and resize it
      8     frame = img.copy()

NameError: name 'frame_width' is not defined
```

Comment: `predict_gender`  --- so, this is the input to some NN, which expects a fixed size ? please clarify !

Comment: you said you try to get `frame_width` with this code but this code is not for getting this value but for resizing image using value from variable `frame_width` - which you have to define on your own. To get image size you need only  `img.shape`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `frame_width` and `frame_height`.

```
img = cv2.imread(imag)
frame_height, frame_width, _ = img.shape
# resize the image, uncomment if you want to resize the image
img = cv2.resize(img, (frame_width, frame_height))
```

Comment: correct syntax, but it does not make any sense to resize an image like this.

Comment: I know, in fact I wrote that he didn't define the two variables. Maybe those two have another value ...